# Applications of the Frankl's union closed conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics

Does anyone know any concrete applications of the union closed conjecture that are interesting in their own right? (As opposed to being interesting reformulations of the conjecture.)

The only information that I've found is a comment that says that Frankl noticed that it could be used to improve a number of bounds on traces of finite sets. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3297v2.pdf